# Scraping image source from an interactive map

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the source URL for images on an interactive map that holds the location for various traffic cameras and export them to a JSON or CSV as a list. Because i am trying to gather this data from different websites i have attempted to use parsehub and octoparse to no avail. I previously attempted to use BS4 and selenium but wasn't able to extract the div / img tag with the src ur. Any help would be appreciated. Below are examples of two different websites with similar but different methods for housing the images.

https://tripcheck.com/

[image: Oregon camera img src]

https://cwwp2.dot.ca.gov/vm/iframemap.htm (cal trans uses iframes)

[image: Caltrans camera img src]

Comment: Can you provide more precise details? What exactly is the data source e.g. the website you want to scrape from? Is it tripcheck? And how does that relate to the different websites you mention in your question?

Comment: yes trip check is one of the websites i would like to scrape from. I previously was able to acquire the cameras from a list view using beautiful soup. However i would like to acquire the source urls from the image icons from the map. Most of the websites i am trying to acquire do not have a list of the cameras and simply use an image icon on an interactive map.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The image names (for trip check) come from an api call. you would need to request the cctv ids then you can build the urls.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://tripcheck.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

params = {
    'dt': '1659122796377',
}

response = requests.get('https://tripcheck.com/Scripts/map/data/cctvinventory.js', params=params, headers=headers)
response.json()['features'][0]['attributes']['filename']
```

output:

```
'AstoriaUS101MeglerBrNB_pid392.jpg'
```

Above, you iterate over the attributes array in the json response. and then for the url:

```
import time
cam = response.json()['features'][0]['attributes']['filename']
rand = str(time.time()).replace('.','')[:13]
f'https://tripcheck.com/RoadCams/cams/{cam}?rand={rand}'
```

output:

```
'https://tripcheck.com/RoadCams/cams/AstoriaUS101MeglerBrNB_pid392.jpg?rand=1659123325440'
```

Note the rand parameter appears to be part of time stamp. As does the 'dt' parameter in the original request. You can use time.time() to generate a time stamp and manipulate it as you need.